# Do I have to downgrade the sass version in this?

Tags: reactjs, node-sass

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

I am trying to run the starter kit of vuexy dashboard admin in ReactJS. I have tried reinstalling several times, but it doesn't work. please someone tell me how to fix this issue

Comment: Please add any code an error messages **as text** to your question. Screenshots of code or error messages are rarely helpful since they are not accessible (i.e. screenreaders can read it, neither can search engines) and they are hard to read even for able-bodied people. You can edit your question by clicking on the **edit** link below it.

Comment: okay, I will  do that

Comment: Yes, you need to. This version of node-sass is incompatible with the latest version of NODE. I think you have the latest version of NODE. Either lower your NODE version or node-sass.

Comment: Try upgrading your node-sass to 5.0.0 https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v5.0.0